# Angular - Can't find value inside array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, mongodb, debugging

Good day everyone, I'm currently having problems using find for array.

Code: https://codeshare.io/EBoBEX

On `line 80` is the code I'm unable to make work. `Line 69` has a similar function but it works.

Error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'customer_fullname' of undefined
```

I am basically trying to enter the value into myForm. I am using mongodb and this is what is in the document:

```
 1. _id:6114e3c1c5934f0fc8da2156
    
 2. fullname:"John Pearson"
    
 3. email:"john@gmail.com"
    
 4. address:"Yishun street 69 Blk 420"
    
 5. user_id:"61003363e8ded0257c63592a"
```

I used `user_id: this.authService.getUserID()` because after getting the user id from my auth service, I put it into myForm as `user_id` which I then try to use to find the fullname from my customers as the `user_id` value is the same as the `_id` for my users.

When I do `console.log(this.customers)`; it shows the following:

```
[{…}] 0: address: "Yishun street 69 Blk 420" email: "john@gmail.com" fullname: "John Pearson" user_id: "61003363e8ded0257c63592a" _id: "6114e3c1c5934f0fc8da2156" [[Prototype]]: Object length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

What I'm trying to do is find from the customers array based on the `user_id`, sorry if I was unclear

Any help will be appreciated, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you use ReactiveForms use `formControlName`

```
<select id='name' name='name' formControlName="user_id"
      (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
```

To give value to a FomControl in a FormGroup use setValue to give it value

```
this.myForm.value.id = this.selectedId;
```

```
//really I don't know if is user_id or id

this.myForm.get('id').setValue(this.selectedId);
```

Always you can get a property you can make it two steps:

```
this.myForm.value.customer_fullname =
   this.customers.find(x=>x.user_id===this.myForm.value.user_id)
   .customer_fullname;
```

```
const customer=this.customers.find(x=>x.user_id===this.myForm.value.user_id)
this.myForm.get('customer').setValue(
        customer?customer.customer_fullname:null)
```

If all the values are related to the element of the array, you can use an unique field, then, in submit you can simple use the element found it: "customer"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it and the following error shows:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null
    at BookingComponent.onSubmit (booking.component.ts:64)
    at BookingComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_0_listener (booking.component.html:1)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15279)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15317)`